# Kotlin/JS browserDevelopmentWebpack doesn't generates build/distributions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I am trying to bundle kotlin/js artifacts through webpack, in a Kotlin/JS project.

The documentation here [Set up a Kotlin/JS project](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-project-setup.html#building-executables) says that

> For building executable JavaScript artifacts through webpack, the Kotlin/JS plugin contains the browserDevelopmentWebpack and browserProductionWebpack Gradle tasks.

and also that

> Execute either of these tasks to obtain the respective artifacts for development or production. The generated files will be available in build/distributions unless specified otherwise.

However, only `browserProductionWebpack` produces `build/distributions` folder.

Is the documentation incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Documentation is incorrect. For the `browserDevelopmentWebpack` task, the webpack bundle would be available in the `build/developmentExecutable` directory.